# vlookup with firstname and lastname

Tags: vlookup

I wish to pull employee information from a table called Names.  I've created a column that contains employee names in the format FirstName LastName, e.g. Joe Blow.
Using vlookup, I get information from the table.
The problem comes when I have Joe Blow, Joe Smith, Joe Jones, etc.  It stops at the first instance of Joe.
I tried J.Blow, J.Smith, etc. and that gives me the same results.
I thought of JBlow, JSmith, etc. but that is bordering on user-unfriendly.

Is there another way to achieve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `FALSE` as the last parameter to VLOOKUP.

Otherwise, it will assume that the source data is sorted and do a binary search.